# how to set a html website to a fixed size so when zooming it wont change size

Tags: html, css

I am making a website just for fun and I need it to be set on a fixed size so when you zoom in, images won't move and info won't get squished on the page.

Comment: Zooming in should not change the layout at all or "squish" anything. It just makes everything bigger. Anyway, you should not prevent zooming, even if you could. It's the user's choice. Why would you want to prevent someone with poor eyesight from zooming in so they could see your site?

Comment: Then how could i have everything stay put but be able to zoom in and scroll side to side when zoomed in? Right now my page when i zoom everything gets bigger making it all squished in a way. So how could i make everything stay put, add a 'position: fixed;' to all of my contents?

Comment: How are you zooming, on what kind of machine?

Comment: I use the Ctrl+scroll. By machine do you mean browser? I'm using the latest chrome version.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a website on which zooming (ctrl-scroll, or ctrl-plus, ctrl-minus) messes up the layout?

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, zooming will not affect the layout.

What zoom does is to change the effective browser window resolution. For instance, if your window is currently 1024 x 800, and you zoom out to 200%, the window becomes effectively 512 x 400 (you can test this by examining `window.innerHeight` in your console). If you have media queries, or are listening to resize events, they will be triggered just as if user resized his browser window. Depending on the result, of course the layout may change, possibly in undesirable ways.

To put it another way, zooming a 1024 x 800 browser window to 200% should cause no layout changes other than those that you would see if you physically resized your browser window to 512 x 400.

Even if you could detect the zoom level, from a user experience perspective you should not interfere with or override the user's choice to zoom.

Having said that, there are various ways to try to detect zoom level, such as `window.devicePixelRatio`. However, there is no way to trap this. You can find other approaches if you google for "detect browser zoom". However, this is a slippery slope. You are better off designing your app so it works well at different resolutions, and then let the user zoom as they please.

Note that `window.screen` reports physical screen dimensions unaffected by zooming. So `window.screen.height` is always the physical height of the screen (not browser window). It's unlikely that you can do anything useful with this information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a fixed height and width using px instead of percentages on all content should make everything fixed.

```
.css_name {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
}

<body>
  <div class="css_name">lorus ipsum</div>
```

If that does not work, perhaps try setting a minimum height and width to the height and width of the respective content. This should prevent the box from ever shrinking below the minimum height and width set.

```
.css_name {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  min-height:30px;
  min-width:30px;
}
```

Comment: I do have that set and it still moves items around in my page when zooming in. Thanks for the help

Comment: What's your positioning set to? I know position:fixed; is suppose to keep things still on a page.

Comment: I've tried to set the body to fixed but it makes it non-scrollable and I did add 'overflow: scroll;' after adding 'fixed' but it would just add the bar to scroll but still not scrollable.

Comment: Instead of putting position:fixed; on the body, put it on each element

Comment: I did do it to the main parts in the page but the zoom still squishes them. I'm trying to make them stay the same size and when I'm zoomed in I can scroll side to side without haveing them all squished.

Answer (score 0):

I used width and height in % instead of px
In this pictures I've got Block px and in % (imgs and text I've got in px)
[With px zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKX14.jpg)
[With % zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLxLb.jpg)
 
Use % on all things IMGS, texts, blocks, but using % is sometimes pain
Example of my code

```
#leftbody {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#e6f5ff;
    width:14%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:0;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:0%;
}
#rightbody {
    position: relative;
    background-color: none;
    width:84%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:0;
    height:100%;
    float:righht;
    padding:0%;
}   
.activebuttons2 {
            border: none;
            color: white;
            width:100%;
            padding: 10 0 10 0px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I took the code from '#leftbody' and copied it to my css code under body and kept everything but background-color and changed width %. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I mean you have to change all into % like imgs , text ...                like                                                                                           .img {
 background-image: url("img/1.jpg");
 width:10%;
height:10%;
}

Comment: font-size: 10%;  on text, width:10%; height:10% on images + blocks

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide your site in containers, for example Top container for the head
middle container for the body and bottom container for the footer.
Then you need to add this CSS code to the 3 containers

```
.top-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 1300px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
```

the images won't move or change size when you use zoom on a pc.
Of course you need to use the width that is suitable for you :)
Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: This does not prevent zooming.